# Adding Marketo Form to Gatsby/JSX

Tags: reactjs, forms, jsx, gatsby, marketo

I am trying to add a Marketo form into a Gatsby site but have trouble with the order in which scripts are injected into the page.

When I try to render the component below, I get the error message "ReferenceError: MktoForms2 is not defined".

I tried commenting out the entire useEffect code block and the component renders to the page fine without the form. Then when I paste  "MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sj11.marketo.com", "XXX-XXX-XXX", 1608)" into the console, the form appears as expected.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

import "./form.scss";

const FormContactMkto = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sj11.marketo.com", "XXX-XXX-XXX", 1608);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <script
          src="//app-sj11.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"
          type="text/javascript"
        />
      </Helmet>
      <form id="mktoForm_1608"></form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormContactMkto;
```

How can I load this Marketo form into a Gatsby page? Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

I've created a simple component for my project. Maybe it would be useful in your case.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const marketoScriptId = 'mktoForms';

export default function MarketoForm({ formId }) {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!document.getElementById(marketoScriptId)) {
      loadScript();
    } else {
      setIsLoaded(true);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    isLoaded &&
      window.MktoForms2.loadForm(
        '//app-XX.marketo.com',
        'XXX-XXX-XXX',
        formId
      );
  }, [isLoaded, formId]);

  const loadScript = () => {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.id = marketoScriptId;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true;
    s.src = '//app-XX.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js';
    s.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded') {
        setIsLoaded(true);
      }
    };
    s.onload = () => setIsLoaded(true);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form id={`mktoForm_${formId}`}></form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow I'm relatively new to react and gatsby and I've been trying to figure this out all weekend.  Thanks!  This really helps me out...